# MVC SelectList Drop down default

Tags: model-view-controller

In the SelectList drop down, I like if the Count is 1, I like to default the value of what is there in the drugfamilylist which in this case is just 1 value. I cannot figure out how to do this.
I had the following below:

```
        var drugfamilylist = (from dt in DataContext.Drugs
                              select dt.Drugvalue).Distinct().ToList();

        if (drugfamilylist.Count == 1)
        {

            ViewBag.DrugFamily = new SelectList(drugfamilylist);

        }
```

I tried but that idd not work either :

```
       var drugfamilylist = (from dt in DataContext.Drugs
                              select dt.Drugvalue).Distinct().ToList();

        if (drugfamilylist.Count == 1)
        {

            ViewBag.DrugFamily = new SelectList(drugfamilylist,drugfamilylist);

        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you wish to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I would have View strongly-typed to a ViewModel.  The ViewModel would contain both the list of available items and the corresponding value of the currently selected element.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public IList<string> DrugFamilyList;
  public string SelectedDrugFamily;
}
```

In the controller you could then populate both the list of available items and the Selected items when the list of available items was a single element.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.DrugFamilyList = (from dt in DataContext.Drugs
                        select dt.Drugvalue).Distinct().ToList();
    vm.SelectedDrugFamily = (vm.DrugFamilyList.Count==1) ? 
                                    vm.DrugFamilyList[0] : null;
    return View(vm);
}
```

And then use the HtmlHelper to build the select box:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDrugFamily, new SelectList(Model.DrugFamilyList, Model.SelectedDrugFamily))
```

However, if you didn't want to use the recommended ViewModel pattern, you could always accomplish the same thing with ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.DrugFamilyList = (from dt in DataContext.Drugs
                            select dt.Drugvalue).Distinct().ToList();

ViewBag.SelectedDrugFamily = (ViewBag.DrugFamilyList.Count==1) ? 
                                        ViewBag.DrugFamilyList[0] : null;
```

And then in the View use a similar helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("desiredfieldname", new SelectList(ViewBag.DrugFamilyList, "", "", ViewBag.SelectedDrugFamily ))
```

This was written free-hand and not tested.  I hope it helps.